# Typescript namespace on multiple files

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have made something like following:

```
namespace omid{
  let version='1.0';
  function boot(){ /*some code*/ };
  class cookie{
    //
  }
}
```

now I want to move the `cookie` class into another file and point the path inside my namespace `omid`. Is there anyway to do this?

---

I have tried this:

omid.ts:

```
namespace omid{
  let version='1.0';
  function boot(){ /*some code*/ };
}
```

cookie.ts:

```
namespace omid{
  export class cookie{
     //
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module"   : "commonjs",
    "target"   : "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile"  : "dist/omid.js"
  },
  "files"          : [
    "src/omid.ts",
    "src/libs/cookie.ts"
  ],
  "exclude"        : [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
var omid;
(function (omid) {
    var version = '1.0';
        function boot() {
        }
    }
})(omid || (omid = {}));
var omid;
(function (omid) {
    var cookie = /** @class */ (function () {
        function cookie() {
            alert("aaa");
        }
        return cookie;
    }());
    omid.cookie = cookie;
})(omid || (omid = {}));
```

Comment: What did you try so far? You can find examples in the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: @Kokodoko import won't worok inside namespace. so basically nothing but import

Comment: You need to `export` statement before importing. Can you show the `cookie` class that tries to import the `omid` code?

Comment: @Kokodoko I've edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You can call `boot()` from the Cookie class by putting the call inside the constructor or another Cookie class method.

```
namespace omid {
  let version='1.0'
  export function boot() { 
    console.log("booting...")
  }
}

namespace omid {
  export class Cookie{
      constructor() {
          boot()
      }
  }
}

let test = new omid.Cookie()
```

**UPDATE**

You have to remove `"module" : "commonjs"` from tsconfig, since you cannot have an `outFile` option for CommonJS.

[image: omid_namespace_png]

Comment: This is not the answer and not working for me at all. I want to use multiple files.

Comment: I have tested this in multiple files and it certainly works. But you have to remove `"module"   : "commonjs"`. You can’t use `--out/--outFile` to bundle modules together for Node.js/CommonJS.

Comment: Could you please post "dist/omid.js" content ?

Comment: The problem is in output file, It'll have two `var omid;` as you can see in my question. the first one is ok, but the second one is coming right before cookie class code, so it will destroy what ever was inside the `omid` variable.

Comment: You are right that `var omid` appears twice in the JS file. But this is not a problem as you can see in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPNyEb The code works, the `boot()` function is called from the `cookie` class as you requested. You can also use `console.log(omid)` to see that both the function and class are available.

Comment: I want to use it in browser, I have a front end framework with some abilities, I want to create this framework in typescript

Comment: Well, now you know how to use namespaces , this was your question right? You could also consider using modules, like the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript namespaces had been invented before es6 modules became a standard. Since then, namespaces maybe has not became deprecated, but their usage is shrinking in favor of the modules. Because of this, there are few people who can consult you on namespaces, and I am not one of them.

But if you are allowed to rewrite your code to modules, then everything is very simple:

cookie.ts:

```
export class Cookie { /*...*/ }
```

omid.ts:

```
import { Cookie } from './cookie'
export let version='1.0';
export function boot(){ /*some code*/ };
export {Cookie}
```

anywhere.ts:

```
import {Cookie} from './omid'
```